# Одновременные операции

Tags: delphi

Здравствуйте!

Подскажите, пожалуйста, можно ли сделать так, чтобы в делфи операции выполнялись одновременно? У меня такой код:

```
TForm4.TreeView1DblClick(Sender: TObject);
begin
if TreeView1.Items.Item[0].Selected=True then Form2.Show;
if TreeView1.Items.Item[1].Selected=True then Form3.Show;
if TreeView1.Items.Item[3].Selected=True then
begin
 Form4.Label4.Caption:='1234567';
 Form4.Show;
 end;
if TreeView1.Items.Item[4].Selected=True then ListBox1.Items.LoadFromFile('21.txt');
if TreeView1.Items.Item[5].Selected=True then ListBox1.Items.LoadFromFile('22.txt');
if TreeView1.Items.Item[6].Selected=True then ListBox1.Items.LoadFromFile('23.txt');
if TreeView1.Items.Item[7].Selected=True then ListBox1.Items.LoadFromFile('24.txt');
if TreeView1.Items.Item[8].Selected=True then ListBox1.Items.LoadFromFile('25.txt');
end;
```

Мне надо, чтобы при щелчке на ветвь с индексом 3 была показана форма и в лэйбл на этой форме заносился текст сразу. А сразу не получается. Сначала появляется форма, а если еще раз нажать на ветвь, то появится лэйбл с надписью. А надо, чтобы сразу это происходило.
Кто-нибудь знает как?

Comment: Не факт что сработает, но можно попробовать в обратном порядке:

    Form4.Show;
    Form4.Label4.Caption:='1234567';

Comment: Была такая мысль. Пробовала. Не работает (((

Comment: Не уверен, что для этого стоит использовать дополнительные потоки, но спрошу на всякий случай - пробовали?

Comment: @teanЫЧ, вряд ли все настолько сурово. Проблема всего лишь в том, что одна из последовательных операций "не хочет" выполняться.

Comment: не пробовала,но я тоже думаю,что надо проще. У меня итак много наворотов для одной курсовой. Они последовательно выполняются. Они параллельно не хотят. Можно,конечно,обойти это,сделать кнопку и выводить спокойно по кнопке. Но это уже дело принципа стало ))

Comment: простите, а TreeView1DblClick определена в TForm4?

Comment: Я подозреваю, что да, т.к. сказано, что форма появляется

Comment: Всем очень большое спасибо за участие! У меня заработало! Я столько всего попробовала,а самое простое не сделала. Я оставила в дереве только чтобы форму показывал. А Label4.Caption:='1234567' я прописала уже в OnShow самой формы. И стало работать

Answer (score 1):

Можно поробовать писать в `Label` когда происходит событие `onShow` у `Form4`...
А что именно писать клади в какую-нибудь глобальную переменную.
Или `const` храни...

Comment: да я все пробовала. И в OnShow пробовала. Не выходит. Я думала,может есть какая-то команда,которой я не знаю или функция специальная

Comment: А OnActivate тоже не катит? Или OnPaint?..

Comment: mike_live! Спасибо! Помогло!

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте немного изменить логику, вдруг получится:

```
TForm4.TreeView1DblClick(Sender: TObject);
var
 LabelCaption: boolean;
begin
 LabelCaption:= False;
 if TreeView1.Items.Item[0].Selected=True then Form2.Show;
 if TreeView1.Items.Item[1].Selected=True then Form3.Show;
 if TreeView1.Items.Item[3].Selected=True then
  begin
   LabelCaption:= True;       
   Form4.Show;
  end;
 if TreeView1.Items.Item[4].Selected=True then ListBox1.Items.LoadFromFile('21.txt');
 if TreeView1.Items.Item[5].Selected=True then ListBox1.Items.LoadFromFile('22.txt');
 if TreeView1.Items.Item[6].Selected=True then ListBox1.Items.LoadFromFile('23.txt');
 if TreeView1.Items.Item[7].Selected=True then ListBox1.Items.LoadFromFile('24.txt');
 if TreeView1.Items.Item[8].Selected=True then ListBox1.Items.LoadFromFile('25.txt');
 if LabelCaption then
  Form4.Label4.Caption:='1234567'; 
end;
```